# In deriving the catenary equation, how does integrating $\frac{dy'}{\sqrt{1+(y')^2}}=\frac1a dx$ yield $\sinh^{-1}(y')=\frac{x}{a}$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, vector-analysis, hyperbolic-functions

Watch, consider and refer the following you tube video named " Catenary equation derivation".

[Catenary equation derivation](https://youtu.be/P-2lqcaFvUE)

At time $00:17:07$, author of this video integrates both sides of the equation $$\frac{dy'}{\sqrt{1+(y')^2}} = \frac1a dx \tag{1}$$

and arrived at the following step

$$ \sinh^{-1} {(y')}=\dfrac{x}{a}\tag{2}$$

Now I understood the R.H.S. of equation $(2)$, but I don't understand how did the author(math professor) of video integrate L.H.S of equation $(1)$ and arrived at L.H.S. of equation $(2)$.

Would any member of this math stack exchange, what are the steps involved in this integration of equation $(1)$?

Comment: There is one step: knowing that $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + x^2}} = \sinh^{-1}(x) + C$.

Comment: Indeed it's best to take it as given. Another way to look at it would be to think that someone, somewhere, asked themselves "I wonder what is the derivative of inverse $\sinh(x)$?" and arrived at $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$. Derivation for that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lRI7-vNfRtY

Comment: @MattiP., How to get the correct answer in Wolfram alpha computational intelligence? I got this answer.https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+dy%27%2Fsqrt%281%2B+%28y%27%29%5E2%29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to evaluate $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx,$ so substitute $x=\sinh(u),$ $dx=\cosh(u)du$ and we have

$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx=\int\frac{\cosh(u)}{\sqrt{1+\sinh^2(u)}}du=\int\frac{\cosh(u)}{\cosh(u)}du$$
$$=\int 1\ du=u+C=\sinh^{-1}\left(x\right)+C$$

using the hyperbolic identity $\cosh^2(u)=1+\sinh^2(u)$.

See also [hyperbolic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_functions).